# Windows batch script : how to attach a string to a number

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I need some help to make work a simple batch script. Let's say that I have a `39` pictures,the first one is numbered as `452` and the last one as `491`. The batch script should do the following tasks :

1) calculate how is numbered the picture that's on the middle of the list. In my case it should returns the number `471`,because it is in the middle between `452` and `491`. The operation to do is `(452+491)/2`

2) calculate how many pictures there are on the list. In my case it should returns the number `39` because it is (`491-452`)

3) now,the picture numbered `471` should be copied `39` times and it should overwrites all the other pictures,starting from the number `452` until the number `491`.

So,I want that one only picture,the picture that's on the middle of the list,overwrites the pictures numbered from 452 to 491,avoiding to do the same with itself.

4) the script should do the same operations forever

I tried to make the script by myself,but I haven't completed it,since I don't know how to attach the `.jpg` extension to the name of the picture,because the extension is a string and the name of the picture is a number.

This is the script that I written right now. Can someone help me to fix it ? Thanks.

```
@echo off
set firstframe=
set lastframe=
set /P firstframe=First Frame : %=%
set /P lastframe=Last Frame : %=%
set /a middleframe=(%firstframe%+%lastframe%)/2
set /a framecounter=(%lastframe%-%firstframe%)
echo %middleframe%
echo %framecounter%
for /l %%g in (0, 1, %framecounter%) do echo %%g
copy %middleframe%.png (%firstframe%.png +%%g)
rem for /l %%h in (1, %framecounter%, 1) do copy %middleframe% (%firstframe% +%%h)
pause
```

Comment: `for /l %%g in (%firstframe%,1,%lastframe%) do copy %middleframe%.png  %%g.png 2>nul`

Comment: it works,thanks. Can you add a loop to repeat the same operations forever ? or until I stop it ? thanks.

Comment: Just a note, if you have a first and a last picture you've to add one to the difference to have the real count.

Comment: @LotPings : there could be a mistake in some circumstances ? can you make an example ?

Comment: [goto](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)

Comment: If the first **and** the last are included in the list the difference will miss one. A list from one to three will have a diff of two but the count is three.

Comment: I don't understand. In the example,the first (452) and the last (491) are included on the list,but the stephan's script is working. It adds +1 to 452 until the script reaches the last one (491).

Comment: The number of pictures between `452` and `491`, including both, is `40` (not 39). I invite you to count them...